# How do you draw a simple redrawable rectangle in Java/Android-Studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty noob in Java and Android Studio, and i just can't find a good way to draw a rectangle. Why has Java got to be so hard?! I have a button in my main_activity that opens a new activity. This one:

```
package com.example.marty.pongtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class GamePanelSingle extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_panel_single);

}

public class drawRectangle extends View{

    public drawRectangle(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Rect paddle = new Rect();
        paddle.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2);

        Paint white = new Paint();
        white.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        white.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        canvas.drawRect(paddle,white);
    }
}
```

My Xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="GameSinglePlayer"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

why doesn't this work, and how do I get it to work?

Thx..

Comment: How does it not work? What is it doing? Any error messages?

Comment: No it doesn't give any error messages. i just cant see the rectangle. it does show my test text.

Answer (score 1):

Easy peacy:

```
  @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.save();

            //Draw something

            canvas.restore();
        }
```

Comment: Sorry i don't get where to paste/replace this code with. I just paste the canvas.save/restore(); in my code but that didn't work. It didn't give errors though. Can you plz say where to put it, by giving a example in my code? Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Please paste your layout xml. And if you want to simply show a rectangle, you can just define a rectangle shape in drawable folder, and refer it in your layout, no java code needed.

Comment: is it than considered an image? I pasted the xml code btw. Thx for answering

Comment: which widget do you want to show the rectangle? the button or the textview?

Comment: Not a widget i guess. I want to make a little game where you can move a rectangle. what would help is: How do you make a rectangle appear on the screen?

Comment: You defined a custom view but didn't add it to your layout at all, so of course it won't show. And if you want to move it with the finger you need to override onTouchEvent of the view. But after all, if you really want to develop a game, I think native Android isn't the best way to go (unless it's quite simple), you might want to do some study on Unity or something.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that easy to understand your code. Its not well programmed. At first pls write class names first letter in capital. Secondly dont call a class sth like DrawRectangle. Its not a method. A class is a pattern for instances you generate. A better name would be Drawer/Brush or sth like that. Because everyone who looks at your code and reads drawRectangle thinks that this must be a method. However:
Once I implemented a small Activity with a net of rectangles that are connected by lines. Here is the simple structure how i did that. I reduced the code as most as possible. This easily draws some wild lines:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ZoomView extends View{

    private float mPosX = 0;
    private float mPosY = 0;

    Context context;
    Paint red;

    public ZoomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public void init(){

        red = new Paint();
        red.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
        red.setAntiAlias(true);
        red.setStrokeWidth(3);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);

        drawLines(canvas);

        canvas.restore();
    }



    public void drawLines(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawLine(50, 0, 50, -175, red);
        canvas.drawLine(50, 25, 50, 200, red);
        canvas.drawLine(50, 250, 200, 350, red);
        canvas.drawLine(50, 250, -100, 350, red);
        canvas.drawLine(-150, 375, -300, 375, red);
        canvas.drawLine(-100, 400, -100, 550, red);
        canvas.drawLine(0, -175, -100, -50, red);
        canvas.drawLine(100, -175, 200, -50, red);
        canvas.drawLine(-100, -300, 0, -175, red);
        canvas.drawLine(100, -175, 200, -300, red);
        canvas.drawLine(50, -200, 50, -375, red);
        canvas.drawLine(-100, 600, -100, 750, red);
        canvas.drawLine(-100, 600, -250, 700, red);
        canvas.drawLine(-100, 600, 50, 700, red);
        canvas.drawLine(200, 400, 200, 575, red);
        canvas.drawLine(225, 375, 425, 375, red);
        canvas.drawLine(-150, -25, -300, -25, red);
        canvas.drawLine(-100, 0, -250, 100, red);
        canvas.drawLine(-350, 0, -500, 100, red);
        canvas.drawLine(-350, -25, -550, -25, red);
        canvas.drawLine(-350, -50, -500, -150, red);
        canvas.drawLine(250, -25, 400, -25, red);
        canvas.drawLine(200, -50, 350, -150, red);
        canvas.drawLine(200, 0, 350, 100, red);
        canvas.drawLine(250, -325, 400, -325, red);
        canvas.drawLine(200, -350, 350, -450, red);
        canvas.drawLine(500, -325, 650, -325, red);
        canvas.drawLine(450, -300, 600, -200, red);
        canvas.drawLine(50, -400, 125, -600, red);
        canvas.drawLine(50, -400, -25, -600, red);
        canvas.drawLine(50, -400, -100, -500, red);
        canvas.drawLine(50, -400, 200, -500, red);
        canvas.drawLine(-100, -300, -250, -200, red);
        canvas.drawLine(-150, -325, -300, -325, red);
        canvas.drawLine(-100, -350, -250, -450, red);
    }

}
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <XXX.XXX.XXX.ZoomView
        android:id="@+id/zoomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the tips. However this code draws nothing on my screen. I still have the onCreate method in front, because when i dont the activity will crash. That may be the problem. Also when i just want to add  one rectangle to the screen do i need to go through all of that code? Whats even wrong with my origanal code? remember im a noob and i feel like i miss a method which adds everything to the screen maybe?

Comment: I dont know what you exactly do. Your Xml itself looks incomplete. It only contains a textview. Do you need that? Where do you want to draw on? I only can recommend you: If you are really really new to java: Learn java first from scratch! If you dont you wont get sucessful result. When i look over your code i dont think that you are INTO java. Android is based on java but its more complicated. You have to work with many librarys and moreover with xml. Xml is not hard to learn, but you have to know how it works. if you only want to create a game in android, watch a tutorial on youtube. Goodluck

Comment: The xml i posted is indeed incomplete, because StackOverflow doesn'tlet me post it. I finally got the answer: I didn't add the class to my GameSinglePanel class. Pretty stupid. However i just didn't know how to do that. I got it now and thx for all the help

Answer (score 0):

How about using a TextView like this wherever needed:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@color/light_green"/>

</LinearLayout>
```